# Why do non-latin characters in Windows 10 path look wrong?

Tags: python, windows, encoding

In my Python app on Windows 10 I use following code:

```
gettempdir() + os.sep + 'storage.json'
```

It returns "C:\Users\3EC2~1\AppData\Local\Temp\storage.json", yet I expect "Антон" instead of "3EC2~1", because actual username is "Антон".

What is the way by which Windows encodes cyrillic "Антон" to strange "3EC2~1"?

I have tried to pass "Антон" to different encoders, but non of them returned "3EC2~1".

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: That may be the short name for the file. You could do `dir /x C:\Users` to see. The [`gettempdir` docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.gettempdir) show the priority for generating temp dir. You could check your environment variables to see what they hold.

Comment: Try running `print(sys.getfilesystemencoding())` before that to see what encoding python thinks the filesystem is using for paths. That will tell you one half of the what is going on. The next step is to find out what encoding windows is using for your system to store that text. My guess is UTF-16LE as that is the default for win32, but it could be some strange intermediate.